# Adding zero to TextBox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, textbox, zero

After you enter a number in the TextBox one point and three zero-how back is printed automatically. (.000) 
for example. When users type 3 will automatically type 3.000 and the cursor will stop at the 3   for continue. Maybe 35 or 380 to write. 
Can I make it with javascript or jquery
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it with Javascript

```
var num = 3;
var result = num.toFixed(3);
```

Result will be 3.000

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer
I do something like

<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var num = 1;
    var n = num.toFixed(3)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

But I want to make it in the TextBox. 
In addition, not only 3 , I want to do in writing from 1 to 9